# Messaging payload contains an invalid "android" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification"

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send Push Notifications with Firebase Cloud Functions with platform specific configuration. I got following config from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

```
var message = {
  notification: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
  },
  data: {
    channel_id: threadId,
  },
  android: {
    ttl: 3600 * 1000,
    notification: {
      icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
      color: '#f45342',
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        badge: 42,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

but got error for `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, message)`

`Messaging payload contains an invalid "android" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification"`

Any idea what is wrong here? Or maybe some samples of proper configuration for iOS/Android platforms?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full code that you're using to send the message, not just the payload.  We should be able to follow along with your code, and also duplicate what it's doing.

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand your point, but for the reason, I can't do this.

Comment: What is "the reason"?  It will be difficult for people to help if you don't show exact code.

Comment: I don't have it :) My teammate already off and will not be available until Monday. And replicate the whole system will too much effort. So hope someone point where I'm using docs info incorrectly or provide valid example of usage `sendToDevice` function with platform specific configuration.

Comment: The problem might not be with the configuration.  It might be with the code.  Without seeing it, we'd have no idea.

Comment: Code works fine without `android` and `apns` keys.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`sendToDevice()` is a function that uses the legacy FCM HTTP endpoint. The legacy endpoint doesn't offer platform-specific fields. In order to get that functionality, you can use the new endpoint through the `send()` function. You may need to update your version of the Admin SDK. You can see an example in the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices).

For the code you provided, for example, you would send a message like this:

```
let message = {
  notification: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
  },
  data: {
    channel_id: threadId,
  },
  android: {
    ttl: 3600 * 1000,
    notification: {
      icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
      color: '#f45342',
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        badge: 42,
      },
    },
  },
  token: deviceToken,
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

Notice the device token is now in the `message` object.

Comment: Can this support multiple tokens? [sendMulticast is not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075132/firebase-cloud-messaging-sendtodevice-works-properly-but-sendmulticast-fails-for)

Comment: Still not working, I got node v12 and Firebase Admin SDK v9.2.0 .. where is the problem?